# Copy/paste html inline image from browser to word processors

Tags: html, image

I am experimenting with html inline images (background: playing with the idea of creating my own CMS which does not keep the images as separate files).

I can copy/paste such an image from the browser (Firefox/IE) to image processing programs like Photoshop or MS Paint, but not to word processors like MS Word or OpenOffice Writer.

Do you have any ideas about what I could do to make these inline images "copy/pastable" for word processors as well?

Example:

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAICAIAAAC6ZnJRAAAAqElEQVQImSXISQ6CMBQA0N7AjYkD4G+hEMLGRGVsK9PCQ7kx0USgDAV6YBe+5UPLnSpu9wzLDJrYnAVpwwNS3B5S6NLTKGxd+2vu9ImJFLd14bWJ9b7sZAa6oIpj1EXmf5/B5nXezoJMDFBzO44ZbhPrc91/I0MXdGKAJkaGFHqGVU517cvYkLGBxgRWQXuGx9JdHkHDYKo8JENz4Y7MoBNkqNxOkLn0fm81MqWZRgG5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" /></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not directly paste images in word processors. To do this First save the image in the appropriate format (png/jpg) using image processor and then copy this saved image and paste it in the word preocessor.
Please choose this as the best answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I am aware of the save workaround. I am specifically looking to get copy/paste to work.

Comment: @Zalumon In that case you have to use some kind of plugin for the word processor which can fetch the image